# How to redirect url in nginx permanently?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I want people type or open some url in

```
https://someweb.com/like-{numberpage}.html
```

will redirect to

```
https://someweb.com/like/id
```

I wrote something like this in the config but it doesn't work.

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name   forum.someweb.com *.forum.someweb.com ;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/forum.someweb.access.log  main;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/forum.someweb.error.log  ;

    root  /var/www/vhosts/someweb.com/public_html/forum ;
    index       index.html index.htm index.php;


        if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /urladmin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;

        }               



      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        rewrite /category-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html$ /category.php?id=$1&page=$2 last;
        rewrite /index-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
        rewrite /like/([0-9]+).html$ /like.php?id=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/(.*).html$ /$1.php last;


     }
       if ($http_host = "forum.someweb.com") {
                 rewrite ^ https://forum.someweb.com$request_uri permanent;
        }

     location ~ .*\.php$  {
         fastcgi_index   index.php;
          fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
          include         fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
          fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
          fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   /var/www/vhosts/someweb.com/public_html/forum$fastcgi_script_name;
         try_files $uri =404;
       }

}
```

I also restart my nginx server but still.. it doesn't do the redirect.

Comment: You'll need to post your full config

Comment: already update. please help me :)